# Import attached disk from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I had a VM (vhd) on my local machine that I exported to azure using a template.
Azure created a similar machine to the one I had locally. However, the disk that I had attached seems to no longer be used last update was from the day of creation of the azure VM. If I understood well, Azure created a VM with an managed disk.

Now, I want to get backups of my vm regulary. I found a Powershell command on the internet:

```
Save-AzureVhd -Source "https://*****/***/**.vhd" -LocalFilePath "\\****\hello.vhd"
```

The problem is that I couldn't find the vhd link of the managed disk (because its attached).

My question is: How can I get daily backups (vm images) of my VM on azure without extra costs (like the backup service offered by azure).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use the Recovery Services vault services of azure and program a daily back up.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for something free to use, not paid service.